# Suitable type for array of dict

Tags: typescript

Without using `any`, how can I *type* properly the variable `r`?

```js
const d = [{ result: 'aEzRuMA6AtQ6KAql8W9V' }, { result: 'N6mkKsnFJj98MHtYMxIi' }]

const result = d.map((r: HERE) => r.result)

console.log(result ) // will print ['aEzRuMA6AtQ6KAql8W9V', 'N6mkKsnFJj98MHtYMxIi']
```

Without a type, I got the error:

```
Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)
```

Comment: You don't need to - given the inferred type of `d`, the compiler can also infer what the `.map` callback takes. That's why there's no error on the access to the `result` prop: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJjAvDA2gbxgJwKYQK4A2UAXDAOQCGAogF4BKeAsgIIBszUAiqwNLMCOBABwB1AJwA1MjAC+AGhgYc+IqTIA5VgFsA1jwhgAYgCkAVmKGMAElACajAB4BJAJbSZAXQCwAKF+hIWGVCWGQ4ADotCgAHAApYzABKJAA+LHDgokTff3AIEAJscIIQAHME3BDEoA. If you're asking what type that is, your IDE (or that playground) can tell you.

Comment: I need it, without I got the error: `Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)`

Comment: ```r.result)]``` is the last symbol a typo? 
In a playground it works 100% fine

Comment: It's a typo, my code is `return { result: [roomRef.id, ...result.map((r) => r.result)] }`

Comment: Please give a [mre], as you can see it's fine in the playground, and the code in your comment above is not the same as in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by @jonrsharpe the code should just work.

Not 100% whether this is what you need, but you can use the `as` syntax to hint a type.
In the following code snippet I have created an interface that matches the elements of `d`, then you can say `(r as res)`, but in this case `(r as any)` would accomplish the same result.

```
const d = [{ result: 'aEzRuMA6AtQ6KAql8W9V' }, { result: 'N6mkKsnFJj98MHtYMxIi' }]

interface res {
   result: string
}
const result = d.map((r) => (r as res).result)

console.log(result )
```